# buefy table get data of clicked row

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

Below is my code:

```
<b-table :data="sortTeachersAndPoints(topTeachers)" :columns="topTeachersColumns" :mobile-cards="false" @click="clickTeacher(data)"></b-table>
```

Everything above works good except the `clickTeacher(data)` part. What I'm trying to do is pass the selected row's data to `clickTeacher` but (understandably), I got this error `Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance` when clicking any row.

So actually what should I write to pass the selected row's data to `clickTeacher`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use your `clickTeacher` and pass the `$event`

```
 <b-table :data="sortTeachersAndPoints(topTeachers)" :columns="topTeachersColumns" :mobile-cards="false" @click="clickTeacher($event)" ></b-table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems the row data will only be selected when I click on it twice. If I haven't click on any row yet, and I click on any row for the first time, `selected` will return null. `selected` will only have data on the second click. And `selected` value will only be updated for another row if I double click the other row. Any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

to select an event when pressing on row in a table using the Buefy library

```
<b-table *add whatever you want* :is-row-selectable="clickTeacher(data)"></b-table>
```